# Integrating a multi-variable function over a single variable without defining a new function

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have a function f = @(x,y,z) ... 
I want to perform a finite numerical integral over x with given numerical values for y and z.

At present, I do this as follows -

```
f2 = @(x) f(x,5,10)
integral(f2,-1,1)
```

(5 and 10 are really just some y and z that have assumed certain values over the course of the program).

My question is as follows -

Since I have to do this integral over many many values of (y,z) (in a loop typically). Everytime, I have to redefine a function. This presumably makes my program very slow. Is there a more optimal way to go about doing this operation wherein I don't have to constantly redefine my function. I need the program to run faster.

Thanks!

Comment: You can time pieces of your code with `tic toc`. Most definitely redefining f2 doesn't make your program slow.

Comment: Anonymous functions are the slow. How about rewriting `f` and `f2` as .m functions, or even nested functions?

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous functions are slow. How about rewriting `f` and `f2` as nested functions? For example:

```
function result = iterate_trough(A, B)

        result = 0;
        for a = 1:2:A, for b = 5:5:B
                result = result + quad(@f2,-1,1);
        end; end;

        function r  = f(x,y,z),  r  = x+y+z;     end
        function r2 = f2(x),     r2 = f(x,a,b);  end
end
```

Would this diminish the flexibility of your code?

**Later edit:** Or even better, eliminating the overhead of calling `f`:

```
function result = iterate_trough(A, B)

        result = 0;
        for a = 1:2:A, for b = 5:5:B
                result = result + quad(@f2,-1,1);
        end; end;

        function r2 = f2(x),  r2 = x+a+b;  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I got a decent performance boost by first of all eliminating loops and using matrix operations instead. How big is the performance boost from anonymous functions to nested ones?

Comment: That depends on the complexity of your function actually. If it's a simple function (meaning the function spends little time actually doing stuff) the difference in execution time between the two types will e visible, because of the different function call overhead. If it's otherwise, you won't see much improvement. E.g. if you phone your wife to buy bread for dinner, it's faster than writing her a telegram. But if you phone her to prepare the wedding of your son in two months, it won't be much difference compare to writing her a telegram to do so. Sorry for the analogy. :D

Comment: What I recommend is using the profiler. try something like this in your console: `profile on; <here execute your stuff>; profile viewer;` Once the code is finished, you will get a browser window with the stats of your code execution. The "hot spots" of your code will be marked so, and you can dive into called functions and see details about where your code spends the most time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to speed up some looping code (an MCMC) with many integrals using the composite Simpson's method detailed in "Writing Fast Matlab Code" available at the File Exchange:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5685

From the document, here is a one dimensional integration as an example:

```
h = (b − a)/(N−1);
x = (a:h:b).';
w = ones(1,N); w(2:2:N−1) = 4; w(3:2:N−2) = 2; w = w*h/3; 
I = w * f(x);
```

The document shows 2 and 3d examples as well.

As a downside, the code forgoes some of the adaptive step size in some of the built-in quadrature methods. However, this method is so blazingly fast, I was able to just brute-force integrate to such a high precision that this isn't an issue. (My integrals are all relatively tame, though.)

Hope this helps.